# How to disable comments on my 2000 Youtube videos at once (not one by one)?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I have got 2000 Youtube videos and I would like to disable comments for all of them.
For sure, I don't want to do this one by one, I want to do this at once.

Something like : Get-AllMyVideos| Set-comments off ;)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: @SLaks: Looks like PowerShell, but I don't know of any PowerShell cmdlets for YouTube. **EDIT:** Yeah, all the other question by this asker are about PowerShell.

Comment: Powershell was just to give the idea :)
But I don't have particular language, I just want something it works.
Here I saw more information : https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:accessControl
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi developers, any ideas? i am sure you have because on this forum they know everything! thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Go into you your "video Manager" and tick the box beside all the videos you want to disable comments from, then click on actions at the top of all videos, then click on comments and this will allow you to disable all comments from the ticked videos you selected. :) This bugged me for hours

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select all videos, there is a tick box beside actions that will select all the videos on the on page to speed up the process